# C# App freezing while retrieving youtube request

Tags: c#, youtube

I am retrieving 200 Video URLs from YouTube. But its freezing my app, how can i make it work, i am using it in Background Worker as well but still not working.

In this i have used Background Worker, i want to add Video Titles in a listBox2.

Initialized Worker ..

```
    worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker1_DoWork);
    worker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker1_ProgressChanged);
    worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

    worker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;   
worker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    int ii = 0;
    int jj = 0;
```

Do Work Function.

```
void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int progressVal = 0;
        textBox1.Invoke(new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {

                                if (worker1.CancellationPending)
                                { return; }

                                    string[] videoLink = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
                                    progressBar1.Maximum = videoLink.Length ;

                                    foreach (string s in videoLink)
                                    {
                                        string videoID;

                                        try
                                        {
                                            videoID = s.Split(new char[] { '=' })[1].Trim();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            MessageBox.Show(this, "Please enter correct video links\nExample : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456789", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        YouTubeRequestSettings reqSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Youtube Comments", devkey, usernames[jj], password) { Timeout = -1 };
                                        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(reqSettings);

                                        jj++;
                                        if (jj == usernames.Length) jj = 0;

                                        string commentContent = listBox1.Items[ii].ToString();
                                        ii++;
                                        if (ii == listBox1.Items.Count) ii = 0;

                                        Comment comment = new Comment();
                                        comment.Content = commentContent;

                                        try
                                        {
                                            Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID));
                                            worker1.ReportProgress(progressVal++, "[" + comment.Content + "] Added to : " + "VideoTitle");

                                            //    request.AddComment(request.Retrieve<Video>(new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID)), comment);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            worker1.ReportProgress(progressVal++, "Error Accoured : " + "VideoTitle");
                                        }
                                    }


                            }));


    }
```

I want it to progress every time a add a title in listbox but its only showing progress in last. after completing whole process.

```
void worker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
        this.Show();
    }

    void worker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        listBox2.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your background worker code as well please?

Comment: You have created a worker thread but you are invoking the work back onto the UI thread using `textBox1.Invoke`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks, yet that works! i was invoking wrong methods. Thanks mate .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the listbox refresh command to your progress changed.

```
void worker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    listBox2.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
    listbox2.Items.Refresh();
}
```

You could also implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your bindings (if you're doing WPF).

Comment: No, not working result is still same.
Also i have STOP button on my Form as well, I am not able to Stop it because app is in freeze state and its not processing events.